# Pushbutton in GUI in ROS

Tags: rqt, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need to trigger a specific function in my ROS node by the user. There a simple pushbutton function that can be setup within the rqt dynamic reconfigure? Currently I am just using a workaround of just triggering the function whenever an int value is changing, but that is not really a great interface.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280558/pushbutton-in-gui-in-ros/) by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-23**:
Using `dynamic_reconfigure` for this sounds like a bit of an abuse of the infrastructure.

Creating UIs like this is typically done in RQT, which is the same framework that `rqt_dynamic_reconfigure` is built on top of. See [wiki/rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt). Has both Python and C++ bindings.

**Comment by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) on 2018-01-23**:
so far I only used dynamic_reconfigure, but this is something i should probably investigate. thx

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-23**:
It's a bit hacky but if you're using Rviz then you can use the 2D nav goal message that is triggered using the Rviz GUI, you can ignore the content of the message and use the message itself as a trigger for an event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As someones pointed out already I'm afraid asking about dynamic reconfigure for your purpose sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

That said, another option is in [jsk_rqt_plugins](http://wiki.ros.org/jsk_rqt_plugins) there's a [`rqt_yn_btn` rqt plugin](http://jsk-visualization.readthedocs.io/en/latest/jsk_rqt_plugins/plugins/rqt_yn_btn.html) that calls a specific ROS Service.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2018-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How about a boolean? That should be a checkbox in `rqt_reconfigure` that you can check and uncheck.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil333](https://answers.ros.org/users/21017/phil333/) on 2018-01-23**:
didnt even think of this, still ugly, but a good fix :)

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-23**:
Yeah, it's not pretty but it works.

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2018-01-24**:
This is what I use quite often. It is also possible to have your code that runs a dynamic reconfigure server toggle the boolean for you. This lets you fire off single triggers from `rqt_reconfigure` or other dynamic reconfigure clients.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
May I please ask everyone here to stop recommending using `dynamic_reconfigure` for this? It's a massive abuse of that particular piece of infrastructure (violating semantics and what not). RQT plugins aren't really that difficult, and much more suited for this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
You could even go for a `rosbridge_suite` approach with `rosjs` or even `rosnodejs`. Or use `Tkinter` as @Airuno2L suggests in his answer.